# JavaScript/jQuery hide divs one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing with jquery. What I want to do is to click the "Hide Me Now" button so that the `div` elements fade out one after the other. How do I do that? I got a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/1/

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <title>Button Show</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button> 
    <button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button> 

    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

### javascript.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $( "div:hidden:first" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
    $('#hide').click(function(){
        $( "div" ).fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

### stylesheet.css

```
  div {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
  }
  #one {
    background: #f00;
  }
  #two {
    background: #0f0;
  }
  #three {
    background: #00f;
  }
```

Comment: You can use `setInterval` check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/2/)_

Comment: @Tushar thanks but that's not quite what i want. i want the divs to disappear by arbitrarily clicking the "Hide Me Now" button. Nothing based on timing.

Comment: `click the "Hide Me Now" button so that the div elements fade out one after the other` says you want it. If not please update the question

Comment: update your hide function- `$( "div:visible:first" ).fadeOut("fast");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $( "div" ).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Here all div fadeout because of using `div` selector instead use `div:visible:last` to hide one by one.

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $( "div:visible:last" ).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Check working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/3/)

Comment: perfect. initially i was guessing `div:shown:last` assuming `shown` would be the opposite of `hidden`. i know. i'm an idiot. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reverse filter like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $("div").stop(true, true).filter(":hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $("div").stop(true, true).filter(":visible:last").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  display: none;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
#one {
  background: #f00;
}
#two {
  background: #0f0;
}
#three {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
<button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button>
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hide').click(function () {

    $divHandle = $('.box');
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        if ($divHandle[divCount]) {
            $($divHandle[divCount++]).fadeOut("fast");

        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

    }, CONST_TIME)
});
```

Please find the required implementation in this fiddle

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/5/)